# CRUD's save method refers to wrong URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need my **Task.save** to go to `/users/:user_id/tasks` but It seems to refer to a wrong path and I get the error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/tasks"
```

How can I solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

js

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', ['ngResource', 'xeditable']);

  app.factory('Task', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('users/:user_id/tasks/');
     }
   ]);

  app.controller('TasksCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {

     $scope.addNewTask = function() {
       var task = Task.save($scope.newTask);
       $scope.tasks.push(task);
       $scope.newTask = {};
     };
   }
  ]);
```

Comment: looks like `user_id` is undefined

Comment: how could it be defined like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't telling your resource where to get the *:user_id* path parameter from.

You either supply it when you call `save`

```
Task.save({user_id: 'some value'}, $scope.newTask)
```

or, if the property is part of `$scope.newTask`, eg `$scope.newTask = {id: 'some id'}`, declare it in the resource definition

```
return $resource('users/:user_id/tasks', {user_id: '@id'})
```